# Solving a USAMO problem using the extremal principle

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

Problem: $S$ is a set containing $n^2 + n - 1$ elements. If all $n$-element subsets of this set are partitioned into $2$ classes, prove there are atleast $n$ pairwise disjoint subsets in one class

Solution:

We consider the partition with the maximal number of pairwise disjoint sets, and we assume the number of sets in this class is less than $n$. In this class, there are $kn$ distinct elements(if there are $k$ sets in our maximal partition). From the original set of $n^2 + n - 1$ elements, there are $n^2 + n - 1 - kn$ not in this partition. We claim there are still $n$ not in this class, i.e, $n^2 + n - 1 - kn \geq n$ or, $n^2 \geq kn + 1$ or, $n^2 \geq kn$ or, $n \geq k$, which is true as per our assumption. Hence, there is still an $n$ element subset, pairwise disjoint from all the others in our class, meaning the class is not maximal, a contradiction. This works, since the original set had elements all distinct from each other. When we subtract $kn$, we remove all the elements in the partition, leaving only elements which are not in the partition.

Comment: My guess is that you misinterpreted the question. There are ${ n^2  + n - 1 \choose n }$ $n-$element subsets that are being partitioned. When you say "There are $n^2+n-1-kn$ not in this partition", why must that be true? The element could be in another subset that intersects one of the $k$ sets.

Comment: E.g. with $n = 2$, $n^2+n-1 = 5$, suppose one of the classes is $\{1,2 \}, \{1, 3 \}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2, 4 \}$. then the number of pairwise disjoint subsets is just 1 (say we pick $\{1, 2\}$), and the elements $\{3, 4, 5\}$ are not in this subsets, but that doesn't mean that any of those 2-element subsets must be in this class. (Of course, because the statement is true, it's the other class that has 2 disjoint subsets, e.g. $\{1,5\}, \{3, 4 \}$

Comment: I mean there are $n^2 + n - 1 - kn$ elements not in any of the sets in the class, since there are only $kn$ distinct elements in all the sets in the class. Hence, out of the ones that are not in any of the sets in the class, we can form another $n$-element subset, disjoint from the class

Comment: We assume that all the sets are pairwise disjoint in our class, and it has the maximum number of sets possible, while keeping all the sets pairwise disjoint

Comment: With regards to " there is still an n element subset, pairwise disjoint from all the others in our class", why must it be in this class? Why can't it be in the other class?

Comment: It can be, in fact it will be, but once we put that set in our class with the k disjoint subsets, we have proved that there exists a partition containing a class with k+1 disjoint n-subsets, meaning the class with k subsets was not maximal, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You may not assume that "all the sets are pairwise disjoint". You are looking for some pairwise disjoint sets, but not all of the sets in the class are disjoint. (It might be a phrasing / English issue in your case, but the clarity/distinction helps others try to understand what you wrote)

Comment: You may not assume " once we put that set in our class with the k disjoint subsets". IE You have to consider all of the worst case scenarios, and not just the best cases that you construct.

Comment: We assume the partition which contains the class which has the highest number of pairwise disjoint sets possible(this number being $k$ which is something less than $n$). Then we prove, as long as $k$ is less than $n$, we can always find a partition which has a class which has more pairwise disjoint subsets, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Also, playing Devil's advocate, your argument would work for $n = 3$ and there are $n^2 + n - 2  = 10$ elements, since $10 - 6 \geq 3$. However, by creating the classes of A) Any 3-set that contains either 1 and/or 2, B) The rest of the 3-sets, we see that none of these classes have 3 disjoint sets. So, taking this counterexample, go deconstruct where there's a gap in your proof (and hopefully you'd get to what I said about "why must it be in this class?").

Comment: In particular, this shows that $n^2 + n - 1$ in the question is strict, IE For $n^2 + n - 2$, we can create a counter example by taking classes of A) $n-$sets that have at least one of the first $n-1$ elements in them, and B) everything else. It's clear that there are no $n$ disjoint subsets in $A$, and in order for B to satisfy the condition, we'd need at least $n-1 + n^2 $ elements.

Comment: As an aside, it's great that you're writing up your proofs to these solutions, and trying to figure out if it's airtight. Combinatorics proofs can be a bit tricky, in part because there are numerous scenarios to consider (as opposed to Algebra / Geometry that is often more straightforward) and because it can be hard to convey your unique ideas without a reference framework. It's often much easier to poke holes in an argument, so ask yourself "why must this statement be true? Is there a scenario which would make this statement false?".

Comment: Wait. I think I misunderstood the question. It says 'prove that there are $n$ pairwise disjoint elements in one class', I thought that means that there is one partition where a class has $n$ pairwise disjoint elements, not that there are $n$ pairwise disjoint elements in one class of every partition.

Comment: The question means "Given any arbitrary partition into 2 classes, show that (at least) one of the classes has $n$ pairwise disjoint subsets", as opposed to "Choose a partition that you love where a class has $n$ pairwise disjoint subsets". In the latter, we just choose the trivial partition (where 1 class has all of the elements, and we just need $n^2$ elements).